# Is it possible to recompile assets from the controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I'm adding functionality to my application that allows an admin to change the primary color of the bootstrap theme for all users. The problem is that once the admin changes their color (which I'm storing in Rails.configuration), assets are not being recompiled, meaning that the color is not changing.

Is there a way to recompile the assets from a controller?

In my _variables.scss.erb

```
$primary: <%= Rails.configuration.color %>;
$theme-colors:("primary":$primary);
```

In my controller

```
Rails.configuration.color = params[:color]
redirect_to root_path
```

I've already tried saving the color value into a database and reading the value into Rails.configuration.color on app start (in an initializer), but again the assets are not recompiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend you to change user UI color with a Ruby global color variable. The main reason: you are not able to recompile your assets for each user will trade the theme color.
My suggestion: Implement how many classes who reassigns the `$theme-colors` value as you need, like the following:

```
# _variables.scss
$theme-colors: black; # default color

.blue-theme {
  $theme-colors: blue;
}

.yellow-theme {
  $theme-colors: yellow;
}
```

Finally, in your `application.html.erb` (or the equivalent) you change the `class-name` according to the user preference:

```
# apllication.html or equivalent
<body class="<%= @class_name %>">
</body>
```

**Obs**: If you use `Rails.configuration`, the action of one user trade the UI theme will trade the theme for all users, instead of use `Rails.config` put this option inside a `session`, reference the `current_user` and keep this preference, or guard this information on your database.

Comment: Maybe users was the wrong word to use here. This is more like admins setting the color for all the users

Comment: Even with admin changing the color, I think is a better approach guard this information in database and change it like the answer